# Inner-Join and group by not showing what I want

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following table in place...Please see below

```
table users:
-------------
| id | name |
-------------
| 1  | mike |
| 2  | john |
| 3  | bill |
-------------

table trans:
---------------
| uid | spent | 
---------------
| 1   | 5.00  |
| 1   | 6.00  |
| 2   | 5.00  |
| 3   | 5.00  |
| 3   | 10.00 |
---------------

expected output:
----------------------------
| id | name | spent | spent |
----------------------------
| 1  | mike | 5.00  | 6.00  |
| 2  | john | 5.00  | null  |
| 3  | bill | 5.00  | 10.00  |
----------------------------
```

I am using the following query...

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, m.spent
   FROM users d 
  INNER JOIN trans m
     ON d.id = m.uid GROUP BY id;
```

But it is not showing me what i am want, some one help...

I have tried the following code...it looks i am near but not there yet....

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, m.spent
IF (m.id=5.00, 'spent', '') AS spent,
IF (m.id=6.00, 'spent1', '') AS spent1 
   FROM users d 
  INNER JOIN trans m
     ON d.id = m.uid GROUP BY id;
```

Some idea...

Comment: What is `ID_prs`? What are you trying to achieve? Clarify please

Comment: sorry, it should be id. what i need to achieve is Please see from the above table  "expected output".

Comment: I've seen. And it is not obvious for me what are you trying to do.

Comment: it's difficult to achieve an extra column for the same row. You want to select 4 columns while the 4th one is a selection based on 3th column ? Something for a mysql 'guru'.

Comment: oh what i want is, take example, the first id 1 in users table has two value in trans table, so when i show those two uid 1 from trans it should be shown side by side not adding new rows.

Comment: you are correct KarelG, that is what i need....help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key difficulty here is that you might have either one or two entries for the same ID. Not only this imply that we will need to "count" things, but also that we have to determinate the "first" and "second" row (remember that tables are *unordered* sets).

It is somehow difficult to infer the the way you want to build the result table (to be precise how to distinguish the "left "and "right" spent column). Assuming this is "min" and "max":

```
select uid, spent as s1, NULL as s2 from trans group by uid having count(*) = 1 
union select t1.uid, t1.spent, t2.spent from trans as t1 join trans as t2 
          on t1.uid = t2.uid and t1.spent < t2.spent;
```

Producing:

```
+------+------+-------+
| uid  | s1   | s2    |
+------+------+-------+
|    2 | 5.00 |  NULL |
|    1 | 5.00 |  6.00 |
|    3 | 5.00 | 10.00 |
+------+------+-------+
```

Concerning your initial question, we only are at "one `JOIN`" of the desired result:

```
select users.id, users.name, S.* from users join
(
    select uid, spent as s1, NULL as s2 from trans group by uid having count(*) = 1 
    union select t1.uid, t1.spent, t2.spent from trans as t1 join trans as t2 
              on t1.uid = t2.uid and t1.spent < t2.spent;
) AS S
ON users.id = S.uid
```

Comment: you answer is almost exact expect some issue, could you please clarify for me.

Comment: if I have Inner join for the above table, means more table..how could join them? the Inner-join table should only be link to the users table? some idea please...Thanks any way..

Comment: select users.id, users.name, S.* from users (here goes some inner join table) join
(
    select uid, spent as s1, NULL as s2 from trans group by uid having count(*) = 1 
    union select t1.uid, t1.spent, t2.spent from trans as t1 join trans as t2 
              on t1.uid = t2.uid and t1.spent < t2.spent;
) AS S
ON users.id = S.uid

Comment: @MR.Test This is probably the way to go. If you have some troubles using "deep" `JOIN` maybe you should close this question and ask an *other* one that focus on that specific topic. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for the details.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 simple ways to get a corrcet version:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, sum(m.spent)
FROM users d 
INNER JOIN trans m
ON d.id = m.uid GROUP BY (d.id, d.name)
ORDER BY d.id;
```

you will get

```
----------------------
| id | name | spent  |
----------------------
| 1  | mike | 11.00  |
| 2  | john |  5.00  |
| 3  | bill | 15.00  |
----------------------
```

OR

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, m.spent
FROM users d 
INNER JOIN trans m
ON d.id = m.uid
ORDER BY d.id;
```

you will get

```
----------------------
| id | name | spent  |
----------------------
| 1  | mike |  5.00  |
| 1  | mike |  6.00  |
| 2  | john |  5.00  |
| 3  | bill |  5.00  |
| 3  | bill | 10.00  |
----------------------
```

To get your output you have to create automaticly new columns. Thats not a good way for analysis in a database and very uncommon. Select statements from other views had to be updated each time "mike" or someone else is spending something new...

EDIT:
The first view gives you the summarized spending per user.
The second view gives you every single spending with the with the user name next to it.

Comment: what i need is to create view to be able to show on phpMyEdit. so i need this format out-put? or do you have some idea?

Comment: @MR.Test "IF (m.id=5.00, 'spent', '') AS spent" you are comparing the [integer] ID with the [double] spent-value. That doesn't make any sense?!